# How do you create a method in objects that finds the highest number using hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm new with hashmap and I'm trying to find the most populous continent using hashmap and I don't know where to go from here.

These are my fields and I want to put the continent in the key section and population in the value section

```
private String name;
private int population;
private double area;
private String continent;
```

This is my attempt for creating that method but it's incomplete.

```
public void findMostPopulousContinent() {
    /* Hashmap<Key, Value> */
    HashMap<String, Integer> dummy = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (dummy.containsKey(catalogue[i].getContinent())) {
            Integer pop = dummy.get(catalogue[i].getContinent());
            pop = pop + catalogue[i].getPopulation();


        }
        else {
            dummy.put(catalogue[i].getContinent(), catalogue[i].getPopulation());
        }
    }
}
```

What I wanted to happen is to put my instances in the hashmap, and if my instances have the same continent then add their population and then compare that with others and then print the continent with the highest population like

```
North America, 100000000
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: When I'm printing that code, after the for loop, I'm getting an output of [North America = 1, Asia = 1, South America = 1] but I have 3 more North Americas and it won't add up.

I also want to compare which continent has the highest population and print it but I don't know how to do that with hashmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *aggregate* the population, which you can use Map's `merge()` method for.

But you don't need all that code:

Given:

```
record Country(String continent, Integer population) {}
Country[] catalog;
```

then:

```
Map<String, Integer> continentPopulations = Arrays.stream(catalog)
    .collect(groupingBy(Country::continent, summingInt(Country::population)));
```

The secret sauce is using the [`groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) collector:

```
groupingBy(Country::continent, summingInt(Country::population))
```

To get the most populous continent, you can skip the reference to the map and use a stream to find the max based on population for you:

```
String mostPopulousContinentName = Arrays.stream(catalog)
    .collect(groupingBy(Country::continent, summingInt(Country::population)))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .get().getKey();
```